# How to get a count rows in a column in table 2 using column in table 1 using PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to count number of rows of table 'proc' which has column called proc_id and proc_dt (date column) using table called 'work' which has column called prod_id and counts rows of today's date.

All the tables have schema 'prd'

I've tried multiple things but its not working. I am not sure how to deal with it! I am new to plsql

```
prd-->schema

work--> table 1 has columns --> proc_id
proc-->table 2 -->proc_id and proc_dtt
```

output--> count of proc_id in table 1 on today's date in table 2

Comment: if you provide here some sample data and desired output it will help us to help you

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). Show us what you have tried.

Comment: How can this be tagged for both mysql and plsql?

Comment: @Sergey I've edited it with an example. It is plsql but I feel it could have been solved with sql as well. Again, I'm new!

Comment: @Booboo I've edited it please check

Comment: Instead of "I have a table Table1 with columns A, B, C" it would be better to provide`create table` statement and sample data: they are reusable and more readable

Answer (score 1):

That looks like **join** between two tables.

Presuming that `proc_dtt` contains only date (with no time component, i.e. no hours/minutes/seconds, i.e. they are *truncated* to midnight), then you'd

```
select count(*)
from work w join proc p on p.proc_id = w.proc_id
where p.proc_dtt = trunc(sysdate);
```

---

You said you want to use PL/SQL - that's Oracle's procedural extension to its SQL. Basically, you do NOT need PL/SQL, but - if you must, then

```
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into l_cnt
  from work w join proc p on p.proc_id = w.proc_id
  where p.proc_dtt = trunc(sysdate);

  dbms_output.put_line('Number of today''s records = ' || l_cnt);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want. You have to specify more, but if I understood correctly this should work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proc
```

Comment: I've edited it. Please check!

Comment: @Vocado_ Still dont understand what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).